# Problem displaying 360° photos when publishing a virtual tour made with 3dvista via a site hosted on Hostinger.com

Tags: publish, 360-panorama, virtual-tour

I'm having a problem and looking for help.

I published a virtual tour made with 3dvista on a site hosted on Hostinger.com, the result is perfect.

I tried to publish it again on another site (different domain name) still on hostinger, but there the 360° photos are no longer displayed, as well, at the same dimensions, even though the process was the same.

By copying and pasting from the file manager, I again have the same problem displaying 360° photos

I try multiples times to repost the same virtual tour, with the same process.

I paid attention to be sure it was really the same folder, same file volume but still have another result.

Even copying and paste it from the file manager didnt make it.

Does anyone have a solution or suggestion?

Thanks in advance